# What am I doing wrong with this derivative? (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, limits, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

I've been doing derivatives with the formula:

Definition of a Derivative: for every $x$ plugin $(x+h)$, then subtract original from the equation.

This means for $x^2$, I get:

$$\frac{(x+h)^2 - x^2}{h}.$$

When I factor it:
$$\frac{x^2+h^2+2xh-x^2}{h},$$

then reduce:
$$\frac{h^2+2xh}{h},$$

Distribute:
$$\frac{h(2x+h)}{h},$$

Cancel:
$$2x+h.$$

I know the derivative is $2x$, but I thought the definition was to cancel ALL $h$'s out. Am I doing something wrong? Why is there an $h$ left?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the definition of the derivative involves a limit, to be more precise: $$f'(x):=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$
So in your case, when you derived $2x+h$ you must take the limit as $h\to0$, which is $2x$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the derivative is $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

So in your answer you're basically there. You just have to let $h \to 0$.

Intuitively, this definition is a way of calculating $\frac{\text{change in }y}{\text{change in }x}$ over increasingly small intervals.